# Detecting cycles in linked list for a sql constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to have a linked list-like (not actually, it's supposed to be a tree structure) in my database, and have a PostgresSQL CHECK that prevents cycles.

My data structure consists of records in a `(id, parent_id, other_things)` format. Is it possible to do this with a CHECK?

**Edit: schema clarification**
My schema is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE static_pages (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    parent_id INTEGER REFERENCES static_pages(id),
    other_things
);
```

And contains tuples like

```
(1, NULL),
(2, NULL),
(3, 1),
(4, 3),
(5, NULL)
```

et cetera.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do it with a `CHECK` constraint, but a trigger can be used for this purpose.

Use a recursive CTE (`WITH RECURSIVE`) query to detect recursion in the trigger, starting with the `NEW` record in a trigger that fires `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON thetable FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_recursion_check()`.

If you add schema and sample data to your question then comment here I might have time to write a demo trigger.

See:

- [Trigger procedures](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html)
- [`CREATE TRIGGER`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html)
- [`WITH` (CTEs)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html)

Comment: I added my schema in the question.